# Как обеспечить точную последовательность добавления элементов в Queue<T>

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть интерфейс:

```
interface IDoubleUpdate
{
    void GetUpdate(double Value);
}
```

Есть класс реализующий это интерфейс:

```
class MyClass : IDoubleUpdate, IDisposable
{
    Queue<double> Queue = new Queue<double>();
    object QueueLock = new object();

    bool QueueThreadDestroFlag = false;
    Thread QueueThreadRead = null;
    AutoResetEvent QueueThread_ARE = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        QueueThreadDestroFlag = true;
        QueueThread_ARE.Set();
        if(QueueThreadRead != null)
            if(QueueThreadRead.IsAlive)
                QueueThreadRead.Join();
    }

    MyClass()
    {
        QueueThreadRead = new Thread(QueueWorkWithUpdate);
        QueueThreadRead.Start();
    }

    void QueueWorkWithUpdate()
    {
        while(!QueueThreadDestroFlag)
        {
            if(Queue.Count > 0)
            {
                double newValue;
                lock(QueueLock)
                    newValue = Queue.Dequeue();                        

                //work with new value;
            }
            else
                QueueThread_ARE.WaitOne();
        }
    }

    void IDoubleUpdate.GetUpdate(double Value)
    {
        lock(QueueLock)            
            Queue.Enqueue(Value);
        QueueThread_ARE.Set();
    }
}
```

Обновления поступают хаотично, никаких отметок не содержат, идентифицировать последовательность по содержимому невозможно.
На сколько я понимаю, если внешний код вызовет метод `void IDoubleUpdate.GetUpdate(double Value)` класса `MyClass` несколько раз в короткий промежуток времени, возможна ситуация, что последовательность обновление будет искажена, т.е блокировку

```
lock(QueueLock)            
        Queue.Enqueue(Value);
```

не обязательно получит первый вызов метода.

Как обеспечить точную последовательность записи обновлений в `Queue<double> Queue = new Queue<double>();`, или же я ошибаюсь и есть механизм который по умолчанию обеспечит эту последовательность?

Comment: Во первых - есть многопоточный ConcurrentQueue, если у вас многопоточная среда. Если среда однопоточная, то Queue и так обеспечивает FIFO, т.е. элемент положенный раньше, раньше и будет извлечен.

Comment: Здравствуйте @Monk, суть вопроса касается ситуации когда внешние потоки вступают в гонку за блокировку `lock(QueueLock)`, может ли её получить не первый вызов метода `void IDoubleUpdate.GetUpdate(double Value)`, а скажем второй?

Comment: @K.Oleg конечно может. В том виде, который вы сформулировали, задача не решается. Может быть вы опишете ее более высокоуровнево?

Comment: @andreycha описал задачу так как она существует. подскажите, что именно Вы имеете ввиду под более высокоуровневым описанием.

Comment: @andreycha или подскажите как мне написать класс `MyClass`, чтобы он реализовывал интерфейс `IDoubleUpdate` и обеспечивал добавление поступающих обновлений в `Queue<double>` строго в порядке их поступления, наведи на умную мысль

Comment: @K.Oleg проблема в том, что в многопоточной среде нет строгого понятия "порядок поступления". Вы подразумеваете под порядком "порядок вызовов GetUpdate", но такого порядка на самом деле нет. В двух потоках может произойти полностью одновременный вызов двух GetUpdate - на двух разных ядрах одного процессора, например. Какой из них считать первым?

Comment: @andreycha моя ошибка, не указал. Вызов метода `GetUpdate` внешним кодом происходит 100% последовательно, т.е разница во времени в микро/мили(секундах) будет однозначно. Не будет ситуации одновременного вызова, но эта разница между вызовами может быть очень маленькой, считает задача не решаема?

Comment: @K.Oleg эта разница все равно может нивелироваться тем, что ОС решит "первый" поток придержать, а вместо него дать квант "второму" потоку, в результате чего он и возьмет лок. Я что пытаюсь объяснить -- на уровне потоков и локов эту задачу не решить. Ее можно попытаться решить более высокоуровневой логикой, например, введением каких-то приоритетов и кастомной очереди. Поэтому и спросил вас про более высокоуровневое описание задачи.